# Paypal donations in Google Play free app from non-profit company

Tags: google-play, android-pay

I am a member of an non-profit company located in Greece and we are about to place a new Andoid app in Google Play but some things are unclear to us.

In our app there is a paypal donation button. Is this OK? Are we obliged to use Google wallet for our donations?

Do we have to verify (with some way) to Google that we are non-profit company? I found this   https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/72721?hl=en
but it does not mention anything about countries other than UK and USA.

I searched the web but I couldn't find an answer to my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

This link hints that it may be coming to play but not yet : http://www.androidpit.com/is-paypal-support-finally-coming-to-google-play, but it will all be from within the google wallet.

I think you're stuck with Wallet.

Comment: Useful link. Thanks you my friend. So, if I currently publish my app to google play with a Paypal donation fee then Google has the right to suspend my app? I don't know if you looked at the link that I posted in my questions. It mentions that 

"You may not use Google Checkout to collect donations if your organization is designated:

501(c)(1)
501(c)(2)
501(c)(14)"

Isn't this meaning that we can use Paypal?

 but what is going on with companies in other countries?